# Geoprocessing tool: different - KeyError 1006

Tags: qgis, error

I'm trying to use the "intersect" geoprocessing tool, to extract the surface of a layer (which I call "streams") that overlaps with another layer (a buffer of peoples). But I got this error "Algorithm Difference starting ... 1006 See log for more details - Key error 1006"
How can I solve this problem ?

I don't have any other information in the log

Comment: check if geometry is valid with Processing Toolbox -> Check validity. If not - try to correct it (read the attribute table in invalid output) and then use the appropriate Algorithm.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to use the "Union" tool, to union a layer (which I call "streams"), with the surface that overlaps with another layer (a buffer of peoples). But it gives me this error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isGeosEmpty' See log for more details". What I can do?

I see that I have a problem in .shp, but I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Hello, I try to verify the geometry but I get this:
Algorithm Check validity starting ...
-2147483645 See log for more details
The truth uqe I am new in this and I do not know how to do. The .shp that gives problems, is one that believes from google earth.

Comment: Me too.  The same problem that causes this error, also prevents the Check Validity process from working.  *Frustrating*

Comment: check validity is not working either: error Algorithm Check validity starting ... -2147483645 See log for more details